# Query for Google Drive App

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I'm creating a Google Drive third-party app for GSuite Marketplace. I have the following queries:

1. I've set up my project in Google API Console using the steps mentioned here - https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/preparing. Now, I want to create copies of this project for different environments of testing, having exactly same configuration and settings. Can I clone this project to create the new ones?
2. Localization of the app - I've found ways to declare app name and description for different languages via project dashboard in Google API Console. Now, for the next step, how can I localize the App UI (to show localised app-strings)? Following are the ways I could think of but could not find proper ways of implementation-

   1. Any API or service with which I can identify the current user locale (apart from fetching browser locale)?
   2. Any way by which similar to app name and description, I can declare locale specific Open URL for my app in the project dashboard?
   3. Can I identify locale through any query parameters in the Open URL or anything similar for this?

Comment: Can you please clear bit more

Comment: Please help me know what else I can add for more clarity?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks! I've added some details after going through the guidelines. Please let me know if I should add more information.